# Access denied by Business Data Connectivity error for anonymous users when accesing external list

Tags: 2013, external-list, anonymous-authentication

I have created an external content type which displays the data from the SQL table. And the external list's data I am displaying the web part. The site is to be made available to the anonymous users. To make the data available to anonymous users, I have followed  [this](http://www.dontpapanic.com/blog/?p=131) steps. But I am getting same error.

Is there any other method to make external list available to anonymous users in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

The external content types is very prone for security issues.

Do you have pass though authentication enabled on the connection to your Database? This means that you have to give individual users access. Which will not work since anonymous users are not actually logged in.

An other option is to use the Secure Store and 'impersonate' the user. This means that the anonymous user uses an other username/password to access the database.

There is a lot of information on the internet
http://tprashanth.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/making-bcs-work-for-anonymous-users-part-2/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893400/nt-authority-anonymous-logon

http://niranjanrao.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/bcs-authentication-issues-login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon-or-access-denied-by-bcs/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/03/12/authenticating-to-your-external-system.aspx

Tip: I also noticed that (security) changes in BCS sometimes take a few seconds to be applied. Make sure you wait 10-20 seconds before doing a page refresh after configuring (security) changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to anybody with similar problem but in different scenario.
In our case BDC was called from separated service. So if you are calling and trying to access external CT from client code, make sure that account under which such application/service/site is running is also set as user in "Set Object permissions".